# An Elementary Algebra (Ratios & Proportions) Problem

Tags: arithmetic, ratio

Let $a,b,c,d$ be positive real numbers in Continued Proportion (i.e., $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{b}{c} = \frac{c}{d}$), then show that

$$d-a \ge 3(c-b).$$ or $$d -a = 3 + (some\ algebraic\ expression) $$

Comment: Can you define "continued proportion"?  Based on the question I guess this means $a_{n+1}-a_n \ge a_n - a_{n-1}$?

Comment: Continued Proportion in the sense $$ \frac{a}{b} = \frac{b}{c} = \frac{c}{d} $$

Comment: The part after "or", is that we need to prove the difference between 'extremes' is 3 more than the difference between 'means', from just the given information that a,b,c,d are in continued proportion. I've tried hard doing algebraic calculation running upto 6-7 pages but couldn't prove anyone of it. Please help me with this i couldn't help myself not avoiding it since this problem is in elementary maths so there must be a simple proof of it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(a,b,c,d)=(a,ra,r^2a,r^3a)$.

**Case $r\ge 1:$**
$$r^2+r+1 \ge 3$$

**Case $r< 1:$**
$$r^2+r+1 < 3$$
In either case,
$$(r^2+r+1)(r-1)a \ge 3(r-1)a$$
$$r^3a-a \ge 3(ra-a)$$
$$d-a \ge 3(c-b)$$

Answer (score 0):

Four positive real numbers in a geometric progression can be written in a form:
$$
(a, aq, aq^2, aq^3) \text{,}
$$
where $a, q \in \mathbb{R}_+$. Suppose there are some values $a\in \mathbb{R}_+,q \in \mathbb{R}_+ \setminus 1$ such that
$$
\frac{|aq^3 - a|}{|aq^2 - aq|} < 3 \text{.}
$$
It is equivalent to
$$
\frac{|a(q^2+q+1)(q-1)|}{|aq(q-1)|} < 3 \iff q^2-2q+1 < 0 \iff (q-1)^2 < 0 \text{.}
$$
What is a condradiction, from which we conclude that for all $a \in \mathbb{R}_+,q \in \mathbb{R}_+ \setminus 1$
$$
\frac{|aq^3 - a|}{|aq^2 - aq|} \geq 3 \text{.}
$$
If $q=1$ then
$$
0-0\geq 3 \cdot 0 \text{.}
$$

Comment: Well you've provided quite a rigorous proof but can you prove it in elementary way I mean other than this- "Reductio ad Absurdum" (verbal) proof, & can you also provide a proof of the 2nd part (after 'or') of the problem again with simple elementary algebraic/arithmetic calculations.